# MYSQL- No connection but the server is running

Tags: mysql-workbench

[This is the screen shot for my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POJPY.png)When I downloaded mysql it didn't ask me to set password for root.It also shows No connection after the download.But the server is running.I am not able to do anything in the Mysql.

Comment: This question is very broad. You'll need to provide much more information. We don't even know in which OS MySQL is running.

Comment: I am trying to run Mysql in Windows 10

Comment: This is a screen shot of MySQL Workbench showing that MySQL Server is not running. I suspect you installed MySQL Workbench, but not MySQL Server, which are two different things.

Comment: yes!!I understood that now.I just installed workbench and not mysql server

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried with the default passwords ? (empty or 1234)

Comment: It isn't asking me for password anywhere.

Comment: have you tried connecting to your server with a mysql client like workbench?

Comment: Try to reset it:
[Reset page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Comment: But password isn't the problem.It shows no connection.Please find the screen shot i attached.

Comment: I would suggest you to uninstall your actual mysql server an install wamp.

Comment: what is wamp?Is it not Mysql?Can you give me the link of Wamp?

Comment: it is a package with apache and mysql:
[wamp install](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: Yes!I uninstalled mysql workbench and installed wamp.What next?

Comment: find the programm "start wampserver" and then your mysql server should start (you can find logs under c:/wamp/logs)

Comment: told you to uninstall mysql server, not workbench, wamp provides you a mysqlserver, just reinstall it ^^

Comment: Yes!!now it is asking for password.But it isn't accepting any passwords.

Comment: By empty I mean leave it blank

Comment: Okay!!I 've done that.What password should i give now?

Comment: Does the empty password Work?

Comment: So do what you want with the password and enjoy mysql !

Comment: Don't forget closing the question

Comment: I don't want empty as my password.How can i change that?

Comment: I do edit the users with phpMyAdmin: http://localhost/phpMyAdmin then click the "users" tab, in the table find the user root and "Edit Privileges" then you ll find the change password option

Comment: when i clicked phpmyadmin i am directed to a page  http 404 not found

Comment: On your windows bar there is a green W  (maybe you have to click on the arrow just next to the time ) click on it and open phpmyadmin

Comment: It is showing me an orange W and i clicked on it.After that i found local host and phpmyadmin.I clicked on both of them.Both of them show the same error.http404 not found

Comment: okay, with workbench, open the connection, top left is a "user and privileges menu", check if you cannot edit pass from there

Comment: that was a long answer :D